# Why I am getting syntax error while installing boltiot

Tags: 14.04, error-handling, syntax

I'm trying to install boltiot, but I'm getting a syntax error.

[image]

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: You have tagged your question '14.04', which is a long obsolete release

Comment: Don't use sudo with pip. You may break your system

Comment: f-strings is python 3.6 or higher. Not 3.5.